# Context of class loader inside method

Tags: java, classloader

I wrote custom class loader which loads jar file from the file system.
the `customClassLoader` override the load and the find method and its working by
How can I make all the code after the definition of the class loader to work with the customClassLoader in context of the method execute.
Once I run this code in the method `f1()` I get this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.xml.dd.myclass`

How can I define that in context of the method execute all the time I will work with  customClassLoader

```
Public void execute()
{

ClassLoader customClassLoader= new customClassLoader();
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.xml.dd.myclass", true, xdmCustomClassLoader);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(customClassLoader);
        ………………….
        F1();
        F2();       
}
```

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192453/java-classloader-change/10192896#10192896

Comment: This post is talking about invoke methods in the declared after found it, the issue that i can;t use newInstance() method because its an interface and i don;t want to invoke method, i just want to make sure that the code inside method f1() and f2() uses the custom class loader

Answer (score 2):

The context classloader must be used explicitly. The normal `new` operations and such will use the classloader of the class that owns the code in question. In the example below, `Executor` is the class that will be the entry point to all the code you want executed with your custom classloader in charge. Load that class using your classloader and invoke its method `run`. You should implement `run` so it executes all the code that needs to run with your classloader in charge.

```
public class Executor {
  public void run() {
     final MyInterface x = new MyClass();
     x.f1(); x.f2();
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(char[] args) throws Exception {
    final ClassLoader customCl = new customClassLoader();
    final Executor e = 
      (Executor) Class.forName("Executor", true, customCl).newInstance();
    e.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i make newInstance to class who is interface i got initiatExpetion.
can you please provide small example how to do this with the above code.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply
its not working because class.forName must get the name of my class org.xml.dd.my.class else it will not find my class.
and i dont want to invoke method on my class it;s class related to run time of third party so i just want to load it and let the code after to work with this custom class path.
why Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(customClassLoader);
is not working.

Comment: You're not getting the point, I'd say. I am giving you the idiom how this is done, not solving your immediate problem. You're gonna have to rework your code until you get it into this form: one class containing a method that is the entry point to all the code executed in the context of your classloader.