# How to use Custom ClassLoader to new Object in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I want to create a custom ClassLoader to load all jar files in some path(e.g. /home/custom/lib).

then I expect that every time I use `new` operator to create a Object, it will search class in all jar files in that path, then search the class path defined by parameter (`-cp`).

Is it possible?

for Example, there is a jar file in `/home/custom/lib/a.jar`

in Main Class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do something here to use custom ClassLoader
        // here will search Car in /home/custom/lib/a.jar first then in java class path
        Car car = new Car(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a custom classloader in first place? Isn't appending the lib directory to your classpath on application invocation enough? This way you can use new to instantiate objects and Java will look up the definitions from dependencies in your lib directory automatically. Classloaders are used to dynamically add code/classes to your application at runtime or to free certain resources if they aren't used (i.e. plugin mechanism)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A class loader cannot do exactly what you seem to expect.

Quoting [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192692/6730571) of a relevant Q&A:

> Java will always use the classloader that loaded the code that is executing.

So with your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // whatever you do here...
    Car car = new Car(); // ← this code is already bound to system class loader
}
```

The closest you can get would be to use a **child-first (parent-last) class loader** such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446671/6730571), instanciate it with your jar, then use reflection to create an instance of `Car` from that jar.

`Car` class within `a.jar`:

```
package com.acme;
public class Car {
    public String honk() {
        return "Honk honk!";
    }
}
```

Your main application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    ParentLastURLClassLoader classLoader = new ParentLastURLClassLoader(
            Arrays.asList(new File("/home/lib/custom/a.jar").toURI().toURL()));
    Class<?> carClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.acme.Car");
    Object someCar = carClass.newInstance();
    Object result = carClass.getMethod("honk").invoke(someCar);
    System.out.println(result); // Honk honk!
}
```

To note: if you also have a `com.acme.Car` class in your class path, that's not the same class, because a class is identified by its full name and class loader.

To illustrate this, imagine I'd used my local `Car` class as below with the `carClass` loaded as above by my custom class loader:

```
Car someCar = (Car) carClass.newInstance();
// java.lang.ClassCastException: com.acme.Car cannot be cast to com.acme.Car
```

Might be confusing, but this is because the name alone does not identify the class. That cast is invalid because the 2 classes are different. They might have different members, or they might have same members but different implementations, or they might be byte-for-byte identical: they are not the same class.

Now, that's not a very useful thing to have.
Such things become **useful when the custom classes in your jar implement a common API, that the main program knows how to use**.

For example, let's say interface `Vehicle` (which has method `String honk()`) is in common class path, and your `Car` is in `a.jar` and implements `Vehicle`.

```
ParentLastURLClassLoader classLoader = new ParentLastURLClassLoader(
        Arrays.asList(new File("/home/lib/custom/a.jar").toURI().toURL()));
Class<?> carClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.acme.Car");
Vehicle someCar = (Vehicle) carClass.newInstance(); // Now more useful
String result = someCar.honk(); // can use methods as normal
System.out.println(result); // Honk honk!
```

That's similar to what servlet containers do:

- your application implements the servlet API (e.g. a class that implements `javax.servlet.Servlet`)
- it is packaged into a war file, that the servlet container can load with a custom class loader
- the deployment descriptor (`web.xml` file) tells the servlet container the names of the servlets (classes) that it needs to instanciate (as we did above)
- those classes being `Servlet`s, the servlet container can use them as such

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you do not need to write a new ClassLoader as the only thing you wanna do is extend your classpath at runtime.
For that you get your current SystemClassLoader instance and you add the classpath entry to it using **URLClassLoader**.

### working example with JDK 8:

**Car class** *compiled and located in* **C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\sources\test\target\classes**

```
public class Car {
    public String prout() {
        return "Test test!";
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    addPath("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\sources\\test\\target\\classes");
    Class clazz = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("Car");
    Object car = clazz.newInstance();
    System.out.println(clazz.getMethod("prout").invoke(car));
}

public static void addPath(String s) throws Exception {
    File f=new File(s);
    URL u=f.toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader=(URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class urlClass=URLClassLoader.class;
    Method method=urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(urlClassLoader,new Object[]{u});
}
```

- note that we need to use reflection because method **addURL(URL u)** is **protected**
- also note that since we add the classpath entry to the SystemClassloader, you do not need to add the classpath entry everytime you need it, only once is enough and then use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(String name)` to load the class from previously added classpath entry.

If you do not need that classpath entry for later use, you can instantiate your own `URLClassLoader` instance and load the classes accordingly, instead of setting the classpath entry on the SystemClassLoader.
i.e:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File file = new File("c:\\other_classes\\");
            //convert the file to URL format
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{ url };
            //load this folder into Class loader
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            //load the Address class in 'c:\\other_classes\\'
            Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mkyong.io.Address");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

source:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-load-classes-which-are-not-in-your-classpath/

---

> Question: I want to create a custom ClassLoader to load all jar files
>   in some path(e.g. /home/custom/lib).
>
> then I expect that every time I use new operator to create a Object,
>   it will search class in all jar files in that path, then search the
>   class path defined by parameter (-cp).
>
> Is it possible?

If you want to be able to use `new` keyword, you need to amend the classpath of the compiler `javac -classpath path`
otherwise at compile-time it will not know from where to load the class.

The compiler is loading classes for type checking.
(more infos here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#searching)

It is not possible to use `new` keyword for classes loaded by a custom ClassLoader at runtime due to the compiler internal implementation of `new` keyword.

The compiler and JVM (runtime) have their own ClassLoaders, you cannot customize the javac classloader, the only part that can be customized from the compiler is the annotation processing as far as I know.

Comment: Code that was loaded by a custom classloader and contains a new operation will use the classloader that loaded that code to execute the new operation. It is, per your quote, just the initiating loader. Due to the delegation model of classloaders an initiating loader can be used to retrieve class information regardless if it loaded the class definition itself or one of its parents did as it should always ask its parents first if they already know the definition of a certain class. Only if none of its parents knew the definition it may load the code itself.

Comment: Yes agree- misunderstood the quote here my bad. I edited my answer and removed the part about it