# Can I bundle a newer version of Nashorn in a war?

Tags: java, nashorn

Unless I'm missing something here, this version of Nashorn appears to have some bugs:

```
$ jjs -v
nashorn 1.8.0_45
```

it chokes on using multiple integrals of 3 digits or more as property keys:

```
$ echo 'var c = JSON.parse("{\"123\": \"a\", \"456\": \"b\"}"); print(c["123"])' | jjs; echo
jjs> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 7
```

2 digits works fine:

```
$ echo 'var c = JSON.parse("{\"12\": \"a\", \"45\": \"b\"}"); print(c["12"])' | jjs; echo
jjs> a
```

3 digits and 2 digits gives a different error:

```
$ echo 'var c = JSON.parse("{\"123\": \"a\", \"45\": \"b\"}"); print(c["123"])' | jjs; echo
jjs> undefined
```

a 3 digit and a string work fine:

```
$ echo 'var c = JSON.parse("{\"123\": \"a\", \"foo\": \"b\"}"); print(c["123"])' | jjs; echo
jjs> a
```

it all works fine using this version:

```
$ jjs -v
nashorn 1.8.0_121

$ echo 'var c = JSON.parse("{\"123\": \"a\", \"456\": \"b\"}"); print(c["123"])' | jjs; echo
jjs> a
```

Anyway, the above snippets are just a way to demonstrate an issue I'm having in my webapp.  My question is - is there a way to bundle this newer version of nashorn in my webapp so that I don't need to request a java upgrade on the server?

Comment: No. But you could add a release note saying *requires Java JDK 1.8.0 Build 121 or higher*.

Comment: Are you asking about legal requirements to redistribute a version of Java with your application? Or about technical requirements of bundling an embedded Java Nashorn runtime with your application and using it for certain operations? Or both?

Comment: The latter - I'm wondering if I can make user of a newer version of nashorn w/out upgrading the version of java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another solution that does not require modifying the nashorn jar:

- bundle `nashorn.jar` (*) as a resource file in your war
- use a child-first/parent-last class loader such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446671/6730571)
- load the engine via this class loader

Example servlet that implements the approach above, and then tries to evaluate your script with both the JRE's Nashorn, and the bundled Nashorn:

```
@WebServlet("/nashorn")
public class NashornDemoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final ClassLoader CL;

    static {
        // In my case nashorn.jar is under WEB-INF/classes (resources root)
        URL nashornURL = NashornDemoServlet.class.getClassLoader().getResource("nashorn.jar");
        CL = new ParentLastURLClassLoader(Collections.singletonList(nashornURL));
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String script = "var c = JSON.parse(\"{\\\"123\\\": \\\"a\\\", \\\"456\\\": \\\"b\\\"}\"); c[\"123\"]";

        ScriptEngine nashorn = new ScriptEngineManager(getClass().getClassLoader()).getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            Object result = nashorn.eval(script);
            out.println("### JRE Nashorn result: " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("### JRE Nashorn failed!");
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        }

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = CL.loadClass("jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory");
            Object factory = clazz.newInstance();
            ScriptEngine engine = (ScriptEngine) clazz.getMethod("getScriptEngine").invoke(factory);
            Object result = engine.eval(script);
            out.println("\n### Bundled Nashorn result: " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("### Bundled Nashorn failed!");
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Result using tomcat 8, on JRE 8u45:

```
### JRE Nashorn failed!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 7
    at java.util.Arrays.rangeCheck(Arrays.java:120)
    at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:2868)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.BitVector.setRange(BitVector.java:273)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

### Bundled Nashorn result: a
```

Web app project tree:

[image]

Before that I also tried simply bundling `nashorn.jar` under `WEB-INF/lib` without custom class-loader trick (hoping the usual child-first class loader of servlet container would be enough), but that did not work. I suppose this is because Tomcat follows this rule from the servlet spec:

> Servlet containers that are part of a Java EE product should not allow the application to override Java SE or Java EE platform classes, such as those in `java.*` and `javax.*` namespaces, that either Java SE or Java EE do not allow to be modified.

"*Such as*", so it seems `jdk.*` also falls in that category (in any case, Tomcat does seem to exclude Nashorn). So yeah, bring your own ClassLoader

<sub>(*) Make sure you can legally do that. Maybe consider using a jar from an OpenJDK build, not copied from an Oracle Java installation directory. Maybe consider *not* including yourself it but providing instructions to add the file to the war you distribute (it's just a zip file), etc.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In principle, I would expect that you should be able to take the nashorn.jar from the newer JRE's \lib\ext folder and run it through something like a [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (depending on your build system) to [relocate the packages](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) to a different name (so as not to conflict with the existing ones in the underlying JVM you want to want it on). You'd probably also want to change the `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` in the new jar that you are making accordingly, and also change the values in the `NashornScriptEngineFactory.class` so that it has a different scripting engine name to use. Then you could add that as a library to your war file, and then create your version of the scripting engine using `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("my-nashorn");` or whatever name you gave to it.

Alternatively, you might try to compile Nashorn yourself from [its source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/nashorn/file/096dc407d310), again perhaps modifying it slightly to give it your own engine name. I'm not sure whether or not that'd be easier, since I haven't tried either approach.

Both of those approaches assume:

1. That the bug you need fixed is something that was fixed in the nashorn code itself, as opposed to something actually fixed in the underlying JVM.
2. That doing so is within the licensing agreement. I haven't looked into it, though it looks that the [source code is GPL 2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/nashorn/file/096dc407d310/LICENSE). But I'm no open source expert.

I would expect that just updating the version of Java on the server to fix known bugs (and [security patches](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml)!) would be have to be significantly easier, but if you *need* to run some specific version of some specific code on that specific old buggy edition of Java, you need to provide that specific code yourself somehow.

Comment: This is a great answer, Peter.  Thanks for contributing it!  Unfortunately, Hugues answer seemed a little easier, so I tried that first and it works great, so I'm going to give him the bounty.

Comment: @andersonbd1: Oh I agree, and had upvoted his answer myself. I wish I'd thought of it. :)

Comment: This one is good too (+1), and can even be better for some situations... sometimes SO's policy of encouragine "one-true-answer" is annoying :-/ With maven shade plugin maybe there's a [resource transformer](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) that can deal with `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory`. The advantage of relocating (via shade plugin or manual refactoring+compilation) is that you'd be able to distinguish stack traces when your modified Nashorn is involved.

Comment: I will add another benefit to this approach (renaming packages) is that you don't have the difficulty of using nashorn objects like ScriptObjectMirror.  When 2 different classes have the same package, you get the weird exception of not being able to cast from one class to the other.

Comment: Ha, yes, [`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.acme.Car cannot be cast to com.acme.Car`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655517/6730571) ... I mentioned that in another recent answer where I suggested a child-first class loader trick, but it eluded me this time :]